# google cloud bucket non project user download large amount of files

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I need to grant a user the ability to download large amounts of files from google cloud storage.

We are talking about tens of thousands of files so the process has to have some form of automation.

It is very important that the user does not have access to any other part of the project so I don't think I can simply grant the user read access to the project and let the user use gsutil?

I can easily manage the read access using gsutil acl and the users gmail address.

Do I have to write some sort of app or client side script to manage the downloads?

Comment: Are the objects all in the same bucket?

Comment: Yes. All the objects are in the same bucket. I can also create a separate bucket just for this scenario if that helps?

Comment: Would setting the default object ACL on the bucket suffice? Or do you plan to change the list of users often? If so, you could use a group.

Comment: I was planning to set the ACL. It's Only one user and the permissions don't change. Ones the object is added It will have the same permission through it's life time.

Comment: The user needs [reader access to download objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#scopes-and-permissions) and this doesn't imply access to any other part of the project. 

You can run [this command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) to modify the permissions using multi-threading:
`gsutil -m acl ch -r -u <email_address>:R gs://<bucket>`.

 For future objects I recommend you to modify the [default object ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/defacl) on that bucket.